# Binary classification with TensorFlow for weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I am trying to train a binary classification model want to give more weight to positive class. As far as I understand, `tf.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` is suitable for this, but I'm not sure and couldn't find an official explanation on how to define classes and what's considered positive in this context.

i.e. Do I need two output nodes and second node is implicitly positive class, or do I need a single node and its higher values are considered as positive class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I understand tf.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits is suitable for this

yes

> but I'm not sure and couldn't find an official explanation on how to define classes and what's considered positive in this context?

in your `targets`, positive is `1`, negative is `0`. You can infer that from reading the equations in the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170305204449/https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn/classification):

```
targets * -log(sigmoid(logits)) * pos_weight + (1 - targets) * -log(1 - sigmoid(logits))
```

> i.e. Do I need two output nodes and second node is implicitly positive class, or do I need a single node and its higher values are considered as positive class?

You only need a single node, which outputs the probability that your input belongs to the positive class.